# How can i dynamically Create Criteria Mongodb Spring data mongo Template

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I need to dynamically create a criteria but i am having problem how can i build criteria dynamically.

I need exactly the same as in here [Build dynamic queries with Spring Data MongoDB Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562481/build-dynamic-queries-with-spring-data-mongodb-criteria) but i am getting an error while i am converting my Criteria list to a toArray as its keep saying that orCriteria does not have support for Criteria[]

here is my effort so far

Here is my query structure

```
{
  "query":{

    "where":[{

              "or":[
              {
                 "fieldName":"title","fieldValue":"Demo Event NEW YORK IIII22222",

                 "operator":"equal"
              },
              {
                 "fieldName":"createdBy","fieldValue":"system",

                 "operator":"equal"
              }
            ]
           }
        ]
   }
}
```

and here is my parsing it to create criteria

```
 if(null != eventSearch.getQuery())
            {

                if(null != eventSearch.getQuery().getWhere() && eventSearch.getQuery().getWhere().size()> 0)
                {

                    for (Where whereClause : eventSearch.getQuery().getWhere()) {

                          if(null != whereClause.getOr() && whereClause.getOr().size() > 0){ 

                              for (Field field: whereClause.getOr()) {

                                  if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.IS))
                                  {
// So i need to append an or Condition to main query for each or object in my query can anyone tell me how can i achieve this?                                        

                     query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(whereClause.getFieldName()).gte(whereClause.getFieldValue()));
                                   }
                              }
                    }
           }

}
```

I need to pass my all where clauses with in or object to orOperator function as a parameter

```
Criteria c = new Criteria().orOperator(Need to pass my where clauses here);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better use an ArrayList of Criteria to keep `$or` criteria as below.

```
List<Criteria> orCriteriaList = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
for (Field field: whereClause.getOr()) {
    if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.IS)){
        Criteria c1 = Criteria.where(whereClause.getFieldName()).gte(whereClause.getFieldValue());
        orCriteriaList.add(c1);
    }
}
```

Then build the main query from this `orCriteriaList` as

```
mainQuery.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(orCriteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[orCriteriaList.size()])));
```